# passing vector<char> to a pointer char*

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

how do I pass a char vector to a char*? I know this problem could easily be solved with a predefined char[] array with a SIZE const, but I want the flexibility of a vector because there will be no predefined size.

```
using namespace std;

//prototype 
void getnumberofwords(char*);

int main() {
    //declare the input vector
    vector<char> input;

    /*here I collect the input from user into the vector, but I am omitting the code here for sake of brevity...*/

    getnumberofwords(input); 
    //here is where an ERROR shows up: there is no suitable conversion from std::vector to char*                     
    return 0;
}

void getnumberofwords(char *str){
    int numwords=0;
    int lengthofstring = (int)str.size();  
    //this ERROR says the expression must have a case

    //step through characters until null
    for (int index=0; index < lengthofstring; index++){
        if ( *(str+index) == '\0') {
            numwords++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here's what I ended up doing which worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>



using namespace std;

//prototype

void getnumberofwords(char*);
void getavgnumofletters(char*, int);



int main() {

    const int SIZE=50;
    char str[SIZE];

    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    cin.getline(str, SIZE);




    getnumberofwords(str);


    return 0;

 }


void getnumberofwords(char *str){
    int numwords=0;

    int lengthstring=strlen(str);  







    //step through characters until null
  for (int index=0; index < lengthstring; index++){
        if (str[index] ==' ') {
               numwords++;
         }else{

          continue;
        }


   }
     numwords+=1;
    cout<<"There are "<<numwords<<" in that sentence "<<endl;
    getavgnumofletters(str, numwords);



}



void getavgnumofletters(char *str, int numwords) {
    int numofletters=0;

    double avgnumofletters;
    int lengthstring=strlen(str);


    //step through characters until null
  for (int index=0; index < lengthstring; index++){
        if (str[index] != ' ') {
               numofletters++;
         }else{
             continue;
        }


   }

       avgnumofletters = (double)numofletters/numwords;
       cout<<"The average number of letters per word is "<<setprecision(1)<<fixed<<avgnumofletters<<endl;



}



/*
```

Comment: -1: Bad code formatting and actually not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member to get the pointer to the underlying array:

```
getnumberofwords(input.data());
```

Comment: i will try this out. I am kind of worried though now because I tried doing it the easy way without the vector and used a predefined char array SIZE. but unfortunately that didn't work at all either. so i can't get the program to work at all for some reason. I haven't had any difficulty with c++ until we got to pointers. now i am going crazy. My output keeps giving me a 0. it's like the for loop is not doing anything at all. i wonder if the problem is strlen. I tried debugging and it seemed to fine in that it did pass the string to the char* but then it didn't seem to work after that.

Comment: @user1066524 "I haven't had any difficulty with c++ until we got to pointers" is like saying "I haven't had any difficulty with life until I was born"

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious is to pass `&your_vector[0]`. Be sure to add a NUL to the end of your vector first though.

Alternatively, use `std::string` instead of `std::vector<char>`, in which case you can get a NUL-terminated string with the `c_str` member function.

Edit: I have to wonder, however, why `getnmberofwords` would be written to accept a `char *` unless it's some old C code that you just can't get away from using.

Given a typical definition of "word" counting some words that start out in a string can be done something like this:

```
std::istringstream buffer(your_string);

size_t num_words = std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
                                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Comment: error C2664: 'getnumberofwords' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'

Comment: @user1066524: Yes, as I said you need to use `c_str()`, like: getnumberofwords(your_string.c_str());`

Comment: with your first option &your_vector[0], i think what you are showing is like the example I saw on the MSDN website for vector::pointer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e4tx21z(v=vs.80).aspx but this wouldn't work because it is only going through and creating an address and then adding and index to the address and then assigning a new value.

Comment: @user1066524: I'm afraid I can't quite follow your explanation of why you think `&some_vector[0]` wouldn't work.

Comment: you asked why I have to pass it to a char* ----the assignment I have in C++ asks us to pass the cstring as an argument in a function to a pointer. we are asked to create two functions. in main we need to ask a user for a string: for example, "Four score and seven years ago" and then take that input as an argument and pass it to the function that gets how many words are in the string and prints that out. then pass how many words are in the string and the pointer to a function that finds the average number of letters in the string. then print out the average.

Comment: @user1066524: Can you pass a pointer to the string instead of a pointer to char?

Comment: the assignment says: //Write a function that accepts a pointer to a c-string as an argument and returns the number of words contained in the string . 
//Demonstrate the function in a program that asks the user to input a string and then passes it to the function . The number of words in the string should be displyed on the screen . modify the program so it also displays the average number of letters in each word.*/

Comment: Yup, that pretty clearly rules out doing what you'd otherwise want.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference of the vector to the function getnumberofwords.

```
void getnumberofwords(vector<char>& str){
int numwords=0;
int lengthofstring = str.size(); 
   for (int index=0; index < lengthofstring; index++){
        if ( str[index] == '\0') {
           numwords++;
         }
   }
}
```

There is no method for converting the type from vector to pointer.

Comment: this only is using the address of the pointer, not the value.

Comment: There is a method for getting the [pointer to the underlying array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).